# webview load html form local Download folder working for IOS not Working for Android in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

We have a html Project inside a folder . Html Project contains .htm,.js ,css and image resources .
(Like Download -> ProjectName-> Project Folder (htm,css,js,icons)). Its store in download folder . 
We want webview load index.htm form project Folder .

in Ios we return the absolute path of project folder and combine path with index.htm its 
Load successfully in Ios . 
webview.source= new UrlWebViewSource(Url=urlPath);

but Same Implementation not working for Android and I tried with StreamReader approche it loads only index .html  not redirect to other page also ...*

*Code For Xamarin.Android
string MyfileURL= "Created path to download " ;
 bool shouldShow = await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage);
 string RootPath = DependencyService.Get().downloadPath("FilePAth","ContainerLink");
 var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
 source.Html = RootPath;

---

webview.Source = source;

### AndroidRenderer

var RootPath = Path.Combine(localPath, "t370_naturaline_offline");

```
        var fileFullNamePath = Path.Combine(RootPath, "index.htm");


       StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(fileFullNamePath);
       string output =stream.ReadToEnd();


        return output;//method return output String .*
```

Comment: On Android, the BaseUrl should be set to `file:///android_asset/":` .Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#android

Comment: No i dont want from asset . I need webview load html from download folder or data/user/0/packagename/customfolder/downloadfiles

Comment: Did you get the `output` from android renderer ?